# Click to call with the chrome extension for google voice?

Tags: google-voice, mac

I use GV to make calls, from my Mac high sierra, chrome browser. I have installed the chrome GV extension, and I understand how it works in terms of phone numbers only being clickable from google sites. However you can highlight a number and then right click and select "Call from ", but what I want is for it to call through GV VOIP, just as if I had typed the number into GV and hit Dial. I must be missing something because I just don't see how to do it. When I tell it to "Call from..." it doesn't work, in any case. So it is not useful. I can take the extra step of copy/paste into the Voice web page but it would just be nice if I could click it. I have a spreadsheet of numbers in Docs and I use this as a sort of CRM and make lots of calls.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I think may help you.

The new default is to make outgoing calls via VoIP.

You can disable this by clicking on the Settings Cog (Settings) to the right of the search bar.

Now scroll down to the sub-section Calls.  Below that you will see Outgoing calls.  There you need to enable the option next to "Always use my phone to place calls".  This will cause Google Voice to call the linked phone of your choice, and then place the outgoing call to the other party.
https://support.google.com/voice/thread/2297665?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I think it is trying to do now. I read that on several web pages, what I want is for the call to be completed using VOIP through my computer and _NOT_ use my phone to complete the call. When I am using GV on the web, I paste the number into the Call field and click Call, and the call is completed nicely via VIOP GV using the computer. But if I click on a number (or highlight the number and right click) it either tries to call via my cellphone or says "Complete call using GV460" or whatever the identifier is for my phone. This is what I DO NOT want.

Comment: I'm sorry that solution didn't help. From what I've been reading, what you are wanting to do is only achievable with certain numbers. The overview section of the GV extension has a note that says:
" - If a phone number doesn't turn into a link on any website (ex: Google Calendar), you can select the text with your mouse and the click to call popup will automatically display (note: might not work with all numbers)".
It seems the only way to accomplish the call is to copy and paste the number, which I understand can be an inconvenience. Hopefully Google Voice will get an update soon.

Comment: You didn't read the question, you are just reiterating what I already said.